# Reload specific div on page without refreshing page in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form in my rails app. I have the form submission as an ajax request using `$("#monday-form").trigger('submit.rails');`. However, once the form is submitted, I want a specific div on the page (the div ID is `monday-times`) to refresh, as this div displays the information just entered by the user. I don't want a full page refresh, but I also do not want to use a partial due to formatting issues.

Form example here:

availabilities/new.html.erb

```
  <span class = "text-muted" id = "monday-times" data-update-url = "<%= vendor_availabilities_path(@vendor, @availability) %>">
    <%= show_available(0, @vendor.id) %>
  </span>

  <div id= "form-monday">
  <%= simple_form_for @availability, url: vendor_availabilities_path(@vendor), id: "#monday-form" do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :day, as: :hidden, label: false, input_html: { value: 0 } %>
    <%=f.time_select :day_start, label: "Start Time",
      :combined => true,
      :default => Time.now.change(:hour => 8, :min => 00),
      :minute_interval => 30,
      :time_separator => "",
      :start_hour => 6,
      :start_minute => 00,
      :end_hour => 22,
      :end_minute => 30,
      :ampm => true
    %>
    &nbsp; to &nbsp;
    <%=f.time_select :day_end,
      :combined => true,
      :default => Time.now.change(:hour => 22, :min => 00),
      :minute_interval => 30,
      :time_separator => "",
      :start_hour => 6,
      :start_minute => 00,
      :end_hour => 22,
      :end_minute => 30,
      :ampm => true
      %>
    <%= button_tag type: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary float-right', id: "monday-submit", remote: true do %>
      Save
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

The new/create action in my availabilities controller:

```
  def new
    @vendor = Vendor.friendly.find(params[:vendor_id])
    if @vendor.user != current_user 
      return render plain: 'Not Allowed', status: :forbidden
    end  
    @availability = Availability.new 
  end 

  def create
    @vendor = Vendor.friendly.find(params[:vendor_id])
    params[:availability].parse_time_select! :day_start
    params[:availability].parse_time_select! :day_end
    if @vendor.user == current_user
      @availability = @vendor.availabilities.create(availability_params)
      if @vendor.valid? == false
        render :new, notice: "Errors were made in your form. Please try again"
      end 
    else 
      return render plain: 'Not Allowed', status: :forbidden
    end
```

When the user submits the form, I want span id "monday-times" (on the same availabilities/new.html.erb page to reload, **but without a full page refresh**. The reason this is needed is because this span contains the times the user has submitted -- once they create a new form submission, this should reload to show the data submitted.

I am aware of the jQuery load function, and I've tried to implement it in this way:

```
$("#monday-submit").click(function(){
    var vendorId = document.querySelector(".availability-header").getAttribute('id');
    $("#monday-form").trigger('submit.rails');
    $("#form-monday").hide();
    $("#monday-times").load("/vendors/" + vendorId + "/availabilities/new");
  });
```

Unfortunately this does not work -- it refreshes the entire page, and the page never fully loads.

Any idea how I can use query to make the div #Monday-times reload on submit **without** a page refresh and **without** using a partial?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible with jquery but [check this out](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: You want the div to refresh with what? Where does the "refreshed div" come from, if not a partial?

Comment: @jvillian I have edited my question to make it more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular task we use AJAX request where to save data we hit to Rails action and on successful return(success code 200) we manipulate HTML DOM using jquery. Here is brief example

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3000/demo_test", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you are performing ajax request on form submit or click on submit button then you need to prevent the form from submitting. Remember you should not submit the form from JS code as it will refresh the page instead use AJAX request to send form data to Rails action which can also return the text/html which you need to render in that particular space. You can do the same by using the following code

```
$("button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({url: "http://localhost:3000/demo_test", success: function(result){
        $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried this using the example you gave. 
However the page just loads indefinitely, as in the previous example I gave in the original question.

Comment: @swilliams I have edited my answer to suit your need

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Unfortunately all this does is stop the form from submitting. Let me make sure I understand you. I am using `remote: :true` and ` .trigger('submit.rails') ` to submit my rails form. Are you saying that I shouldn't do this and should use solely ajax  request to submit the form?

Comment: YES... when you are using remote:true you don't need to submit form manually

Comment: Thanks. However, as before, this is still yielding the page reloading indefinitely, even when I use e.preventDefault().

Comment: can you edit your question and add your form code and controller code which you are using? So that it is more understandable that what you are doing

Comment: I edited it to make it more clear. I hope this helps! Thanks so much for your help

Comment: remote:true should be on form instead of submit button

Comment: You can also have more understanding how AJAX, unobtrusive javascript and rails works with various tutorial one of them is https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-c37fc757d8b1